# android- can not make the app multi language

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to have a multi language app , I've made the recourse file like this :

[image]

I've put a string inside each string.xml file "welcome" with the different translates

this is my class :

```
public class MyContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper {

public MyContextWrapper(Context base) {
    super(base);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, String language) {
    Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    Locale sysLocale = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        sysLocale = getSystemLocale(config);
    } else {
        sysLocale = getSystemLocaleLegacy(config);
    }
    if (!language.equals("") && !sysLocale.getLanguage().equals(language)) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            setSystemLocale(config, locale);
        } else {
            setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
        }

    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return new MyContextWrapper(context);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Locale getSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config){
    return config.locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static Locale getSystemLocale(Configuration config){
    return config.getLocales().get(0);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale){
    config.locale = locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale){
    config.setLocale(locale);
}
```

this is my first activity and how I call it  :

```
 @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(MyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase,"fa"));
}
```

the problem is , it always returns the value from values directory , so it doesn't work .

what is wrong ?

Comment: You don't set the locale.  You use the phone's locale.  If you want to see the language change, change it in settings for the phone.  If you try update configuration hacks, you're going to be fighting the system every step of the way-  it is very much NOT recommended.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for your reply , I want make user to choose the language and I use that language in my app , what do you recommend ?

Comment: I recommend not doing that.  The system isn't set up for it, and it really isn't a feature most users want-  they have the phone in the language they want apps in, and that rarely changes.

Answer (score 0):

try this code to change language of your app whatever the device language  :

```
   Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
   Locale.setDefault(locale);
   Resources res = context.getResources();
   Configuration config = new Configuration();
   DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
   config.locale = locale;
   context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, dm);
```

Comment: as I said I want user to choose the language not the phone language